# Calling a javascript function from a link

Tags: jquery

I have the following:

```
    <li><a id="register" 
        class="access button red"
        data-action="Register" 
        title="Login"><span class="smaller">REGISTER</span></a></li>
    <li><a id="login" 
        class="access button red"
        data-action="Login" 
        title="Login"><span class="smaller">LOGIN</span></a></li>
```

Is there an easy way in jQuery that I could make the clicking of one of these links call a 
javascript function and pass in the data-action as an argument. I put in the class called
"access" as I think I could use this to pick out these two links but then I am not sure 
what to do next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
​$('a.access')​.click(function() {
    console.log($(this).data('action'));
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zerkms/EWSCJ/

So within event handler you have `this` as a DOM-object, or `$(this)` as a jQuery object. So you can use `.data()` jQuery method to retrieve `data-action` value

Answer (score 2):

one line

```
$("a.access").click(function(){ doSomeThing($(this).attr("data-action"))  })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use one of following samples, [`event.preventDefault();`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) will stop navigating to the hyperlink.

```
$("a.access").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    customFunction($(this).attr("data-action"));
});
```

or

```
$("a.access").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    customFunction($(this).data("action"));
});​
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely. Just do something like this:

```
var callback = function() {
  var $el = $(this);
  alert($el.data('action'));
};​

$('#login').click(callback)
```